# How to create array from a CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

How can I split a csv file into arrays? If the row starts with the letter M I would create a new array and push next lines to it until I had again a row with letter M.

At this moment I push all staff to same array.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) {
 

   if($data[0] == 'M'){
      $customerDetail[$x] = $data;
     
    }
    else {
      $customerDetail[] = $data;
      
    }
  
    $x++;
   
  }    
  fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say "table", because currently all I see is an _array_.

Comment: Please give a short example for your input content and desired output content. A couple rows for each would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The main concept is there, using `$x` to keep track of the array position, but you then go back and just add the next values to the same part level of the array.

This code adds the missing part which is a multidimensional array, so `$x` is the main thing that keeps track of which set of data you are in and you just add it into that dimension of the array (using `[$x][]`) till the next M occurs...

```
$customerDetail = [[]];
$x = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) {
   if($data[0] == 'M'){
      $x++;
      $customerDetail[$x] = [];
    }
    $customerDetail[$x][] = $data;
}    
fclose($handle);
```